# Modifying the `clear` attribute of an image with TinyMCE

Tags: python, django, django-tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE with the `tinymce-django` app in my Django website. I am using it in the admin interface to edit HTML fields. (Something like a flatpage.)

When adding images with TinyMCE, how can I change their `clear` style attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First go to the **image popup**. After selecting image, navigate to **Appearance** tab.

If you don't see this popup, make sure that the editor mode is *advanced* and the plugin *advimage* is included.

Now, you have two options to do so:

1. **CSS class**. You have to define, for example, `.clear { clear: both; }`
    in your CSS stylesheet. In TinyMCE you will see the class, select *clear*.
    If you don't see your class that's probably because you didn't include the stylesheet in *content_css*, but you can still select *(value)* and type it yourself.
2. **CSS style**. Add *clear: both;* (or right/left, whatever you need), in the style row.

I've made an screenshot of both options, you need only one of them:

[image: TinyMCE Appearance tab]

It is possible to edit the style manually, in **HTML popup**. If the editor is intended for developers, then this is the easist approach, and probably also the fastest one.

Comment: Where did you get that pop-up? I'm getting a much less detailed popup without all these options!

Comment: @cool-RR Here: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php . Maybe you are in simple mode? Check that you've included all plugins (and then eliminate plugins that you don't need).

Comment: The needed plugin was `advimage`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have clear included in the [valid elements](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/valid_elements) rules (or the [extended valid elements](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/extended_valid_elements)), or TinyMCE will strip it out.

Comment: I went over both links, and I don't understand. It seems this setting determines which tags can be used. `img` is already enabled with `style`. (`clear` is a style, not an HTML attribute.) Also, just because something is listed there doesn't mean the user can edit it in the "image options" pop-up.
Anyway, I tried adding it, didn't work.

Comment: OK, sorry, in that case I don't know.